# What is the maximum norm induced by the maximum norm for $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm reading a problem which uses the matrix norm  induced by the maximum norm for $\mathbb{R}^n$. But I  do know what it is exactly, and googling it gives different results.

Comment: What different results did you find?

Comment: Did not really collect them. What is your thoughts @saulspatz ?

Comment: My thought is that I can't explain the differences without knowing the results.

Comment: @saulspatz https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm under "Max norm". 
And the other is  the one in my textbook: 
(Theorem on Infinity Matrix Norm)
If the vector norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ is defined by
$$
\|x\|_{\infty}=\max _{1 \leq i \leq n}\left|x_{i}\right|
$$
then its subordinate matrix norm is given by
$$
\|A\|_{\infty}=\max _{1 \leq i \leq n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left|a_{i j}\right|
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix norm described in your textbook is what is described at the beginning of the Wikipedia article.  (Note that any norm on the vectors will induce a norm on the matrices.)

The "entrywise norms" that the article describes later are not norms in this sense.  They aren't induced by vector norms.  As the article points out sometimes the same notation is used for different things.  The "max norm" is one of these entrywise norms.

The max norm just treats the matrix as if it were a vector, with the entries written in a rectangular array instead of a line.  It doesn't have anything to do with the matrix as an operator on vectors.

Comment: So that is the answer on my question :

What is the maximum norm induced by the maximum norm for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ?

Comment: @Xenusi It's the one described as $\parallel A\parallel_\infty$ in the article